# ASP.NET Core WEB API: Required parameter with conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My property needs to be 7, 30 or 60.

```
[Required]
public int FrequenciaConsulta { get; set; }
```

Is there something like '[Required]' that checks the values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a custom validation attribute.

```
public class RequiredNumberAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    private int[] allowedNumbers;

    public RequiredNumberAttribute(params int[] numbers)
    {
         allowedNumbers = numbers;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        int number = (int)value;

        if (allowedNumbers.Contains(number))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        return new ValidationResult($"Error: Number must be {string.Join(",", allowedNumbers)}");
    }
```

Usage would be:

```
[RequiredNumber(7,30,60)]
public int FrequenciaConsulta { get; set; }
```

Comment: Switched to `object value` instead of `ValidationContext.ObjectInstance` because I'm not sure of the conditions [where the object may not be properly initialized](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/ValidationContext.cs#L105).

Comment: @yuriy Thanks for updating with the appropriate method.  I had forgotten that would work.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!